# How to have just one form on several Twitter Bootstrap tabs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to have one form one several Twitter Bootstrap tabs?

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
    </li>            
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="1">
      <form id="personal-data" class="form-horizontal">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
      <!-- form controls to be continued here -->
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>            
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What's wrong of having one `<form>` that wraps everything up?

```
<form id="personal-data" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#">

<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
    </li>            
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="1">      
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
      <!-- form controls to be continued here -->
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>            
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

are you submitting **tab by tab** or once on the **last tab**?

if **one-by-one** (for exemple, validation), simply use `$.post` to send data back and forward on-the-fly (in other words, make ajax calls).

Comment: Thanks, @balexandre. What should I do with `<fieldset>`? May I have several `<fieldset>`?

Comment: Note that you will need to override some of the bootstrap.css if you want a form that spans tabs (and looks good). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694961/html-form-spanning-bootstrap-tabs-causing-odd-spacing/10694984#10694984

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into the same problem, if you want to submit once in the last tab, I assume there's a button somewhere to move beetwen tabs. By default clicking those buttons will trigger the POST request. To prevent this add following line to your button click funciton:

> ```
> event.preventDefault();
> ```