# submit multiple forms synchronously in django

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way to submit simultaneously two forms connected through a foreign key in django?

I need to send them in order, so the best idea is to use synchronous option, right?

Any ideas? A simple example would be very useful!

**Edit**: Each form is on a different tab in the template. I have 5 tabs so I have five form tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post 2 forms at the same time using prefixes. Let's say you have these models:
Post => Category and you want to save a post and a category at the same time.

In your view:

```
post_form = PostForm(prefix="post", ...)
category_form = CategoryForm(prefix="category", ...)

...
if post_form.is_valid() and category_form.is_valid():
   ...
```

In your template you just show them within the same form tag.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not suitable for me. I must have two form tags because I have one form per tab on the same template. I have five tabs.

Comment: If you cannot put all the fields under the same form (you still could put the tabs in the form), just use jquery to post all the fields. Now on the server side, that doesn't change my answer, you need form prefixes. Why would you post several tabs at once anyway, that's a really weird UI.

Comment: How to put tabs in one form?

Comment: Google it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233142/how-to-have-just-one-form-on-several-twitter-bootstrap-tabs